# Selenium: Injected text disappears after a few seconds when using send_keys() method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im writing a data-entry script and came across a problem while working with selenium's send_keys() method. As the subject mentions, the injected text disappears after appearing for a couple of seconds I'm using selenium to interact with a website's text input field.

**SUSPECTED HTML ELEMENT `dx_field`**

```
<input class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm" wire:model.debounce.500ms="search_diagnoses.0" type="text" placeholder="Search diagnosis...">
```

This element is added everytime an "Add New Diagnosis" button is clicked. And when a diagnosis is typed an unordered list appears with autocomplete suggestions, THE USER MUST CLICK an option listed on the to add the diagnosis.

So to handle a visit with multiple diagnoses I implemented the following code to inject text into the desired field.

**Implementation**

```
 while count < dx_count:
    driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,value="button[class='btn btn-sm btn-secondary font-medium text-sm text-gray-700']").click()
    print(f"Current Count {count}")
    xpath_id = [7,10,13,16,19]
    dx_field = None
    dx_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,f'//*[@id="919e06c4ea7e2a5bb720134d693a8671"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div[{xpath_id[count]}]/div[2]/input')))
    try:
       ActionChains(driver).send_keys_to_element(dx_field,patient.diagnosis[index]).perform()
       wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.XPATH,f'//*[@id="919e06c4ea7e2a5bb720134d693a8671"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div[{xpath_id[count]}]/div[2]/input'),patient.diagnosis[index]))
    except:
       driver.refresh()
       self.record_visit(patient)
```

The code works as expected for the first few vists, with the text being injected successfully. However after trying to populate the diagnosis fields for the 4th patient's visit the injected text appears and disppears from the element failing to show the autocomplete suggestions needed to make a selection.

Solutions I tried:

- I suspected that the text field was not in focus, so I used `dx_field.click()`, and `dx_field.clear()` to solve the problem. However the text still disappears after the 4th patient's visit.
- I suspected that `send_keys()` was being debounced because of the input element's `wire:model.debounce.500ms` property, so I injected the text char by char with a 0.1s then 0.5s between each char using `time.sleep()` but the text still disappears after the 4th patient's vist.
- I suspected that `send_keys()` wasn't behaving as expected so I used selenium's `ActionChains(driver).send_keys_to_element(dx_field,patient.diagnosis[index]).perform()` and JsExecutor's `driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].value='{patient.diagnosis[index]}'", dx_field)` as an alternative. With `send_keys_to_element()` and `execute_script()` the text injected still disppears from the `dx_field` element.
- I suspected that the element wasn't fully loaded, so I used `driver.get("url")` to ensure the DOM was completely loaded before attempting to populate a visit form, the text still disappears from the element.

Additional Info:

- Using Chrome Version 107.0.5304.110 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- On Mac OS Big Sur Version 11.7
- Using Selenium 4.5.0

Comment: I love how detailed the question was. Did you finally find an answer to this?

Comment: @PrakharRathi Hi, yes the raw string being imported from a separate file contained spaces before and after the desired text so the structure looked like "  Desired Text   ", the solution was to use python's .strip() string method to remove the unwanted spaces and after doing so the program continued to work without problems.